# Weightest Rankings Table for Office Pool League

Tags: matrices, statistics

My office recently got a pool table and many of us here are quite competitive, others are not but everyone is interested in a office pool ranking system.

I have created a spreadsheet system for logging results but I cannot figure out a way of ranking fairly.

I ideally we would like to have a system of weighted rankings, so if a low ranked player (say using data from the last month) beats the office pool champ it has a higher effect than than if the office champ beats Mr low-rank.

I thought about a system of using only the scores against OTHER opponents to use for the adjusting of the players rankings but I can't figure out a system where this works. it seems like high ranking players might lose ranking by beating lower level opposition.

All the matches are just W/L checks, no other variables.

Does anyone know if a sensible matrix/formula/not sure that would be good for us to use here. This one has be a little stumped.

Comment: You could start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_rating_system

Comment: Thanks for that, wasn't aware of the chess ranking system. I'll give it a reed and see if i can't implement it into my sheet.